# How to fix TextOverflow strange symbol?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

If text overflowed, after 3 dots rendered strange symbol. How to solve that?

```
 Text(
                          'Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title ',
                          style: layout.theme.textTheme.styleSB16,
                          maxLines: 3,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you provide a print screen or image of that "strange symbol" so that we can understand better?

Comment: wrap your textwidget in expanded or flexible.

Comment: @Eduardo already uploaded in question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove 3dots, delete this line of code:

```
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
```

Comment: already was used

Comment: I mean remove it. Did you test it?

Comment: I want to use overflow, but after 3 dot i got a strange symbol, pls look to the question again, it was updated